# Having trouble passing an object into the constructor of another class in C++

Tags: c++

I cannot for the life of me work out why this isn't working... Can't compile, keep getting an error "no matching function for call to 'Duty::Duty()'" for the line with the changeDuty constructor. I think it thinks I'm trying to call one of the Duty class constructors? But I just want to pass in a Duty class object!

```
class Duty
  {
  string Chore;
  string Member;

  public:
  Duty(string dutyInfo);
  Duty(string chore, string member) {Chore = chore; Member = member;}
  };

class changeDuty
  {
  Duty Original;

  public:
  changeDuty(Duty original) {Original = original;}
  };
```

After perusing similar questions, I've tried using

```
changeDuty(Duty& original) {Original = original;}
```

and

```
changeDuty(const Duty& original) {Original = original;}
```

Still no dice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Classes should not usually be named verbs.  You probably need to revisit your class layout.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to accept the best answer to your questions (click the empty check mark below the answer's score), as well as up-voting any good answer you see.

Comment: Don't worry, changeDuty is a class where objects are an instance of a duty which needs to be changed, so that would be acceptable?

Comment: Should it be named DutyChanger then?

Comment: No because it doesn't actually change anything, it just holds information about the duty to be changed... I guess if anything, changeDutyRequest would be most apropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
changeDuty(Duty original) {Original = original;}
```

This first default-constructs `Original`, then reassigns it.  But there is no default constructor, so it is an error.  What you wanted was:

```
changeDuty(Duty original) : Original(original) {}
```

which copy-constructs `Original`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a default constructor. An empty one will do:

```
Duty();
```

Since you're doing this:

```
Duty Original;
```

The compiler needs to be able to construct a `Duty` object with a constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: No default constructor is needed.  Passing the correct arguments to the constructor is needed.